# CustomSecurityAttributes on idToken

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

At Azure AD, is there a way of adding CustomSecurityAttributes to the idToken?

I've tried looking all over the documentation for that and haven't found a solution yet. I want to get this user information at idToken claim.

Comment: in Azure AD, you can't add custom attributes to the id_token directly , but you can use optional claims to achieve something similar.

Comment: That might work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD, you can't add custom attributes to the `id_token` directly in the way that you might expect, but you can use optional claims to achieve something similar. Here's how you can include user attributes in the `id_token`:

##### 1. Add Custom Attributes:

Firstly, if you haven't done so Navigate to Azure Active Directory > Custom attributes and add your custom attributes.

##### 2. Map Custom Attributes to Optional Claims:

1. In the Azure Portal, go to Azure Active Directory > App registrations.
2. Find and click on your application.
3. Under the "Token configuration" section, you'll have an option to add optional claims.
4. Click on "Add optional claim", and for the `id_token` token type, you can select the claims (attributes) you want to include.

or you can  Edit the Application Manifest:

1. Still in the App registration for your application, click on "Manifest".
2. You'll see a JSON representation of your application. There's a `optionalClaims` section in which you can manually specify additional claims for `id_tokens`, `access_tokens`, and `saml_tokens`.
3. Add your custom attributes (claims) there.

example:

```json
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "customAttribute",
            "source": "user",
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
    ...
},
```

replace `"customAttribute"` with the name of your custom attribute.

##### 3. Ensure Proper Permissions

Finally, ensure your application has permissions to read the attributes you've added. This might require you to set appropriate delegated or application permissions.

After making these changes, when a user signs in, the `id_token` should contain the desired attributes.

More Information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims